# Javascript reading labels from objects in an array

Tags: javascript

How to pass labels of data to .domain argument ?

```
var data = {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12, f:3, g:7, h:14}
 
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"])
  .range(d3.schemeDark2);
```

So instead having `.domain(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"])`
I would like to have .domain(how to get labels from data variable ?)

Comment: `Object.keys(data)` - it's the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) you can get all names.

```js
var data = {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12, f:3, g:7, h:14}
var keys = Object.keys(data);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(keys)
  .range(d3.schemeDark2);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I am wondering if start a new topic or ask here: d3.schemeDark2 has only 8 colours, so I wonder what will happen if I will have 35 labels becouse this is maximum count of them. And it is dynamic, the data variable can have 1 - 35 keys so how to create color variable properly?